# C# HttpClient returns error 500 (Internal Server Error) once per several calls

Tags: c#, httpclient

My web application connects to back-end using HttpClient. Generally it works, but once per 10=15 calls error 500 appears. When page is reloaded it goes ok. The error appears in code where connection is made to backend with HttpClient object. My web application is using **Unity as IOC**.

I made a few trials before current code:
- HttpClientHelper had static field  `static HttpClient httpClient` which was not disposed in code

but still error 500 appears.

**BUT**: when I do a lot of calls from external app like Fiddler, the error is not appearing . I did about 150 quick calls and no error appeared.

UPDATE1:

My request from fiddler is :

```
GET http://www.zzz.com/methodA HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic **********************
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.5
Host:www.zzz.com
```

Response from fiddler is :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2016 14:06:34 GMT
Content-Length: 36

{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

UPDATE 2:

I changed code so httpClient is a static property. But still the same issue. **The code of HttpClientHelper class is started from async/await, maybe this is a problem?**

UPDATE3:
I created new post, it's more detailed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367225/how-to-syncronize-static-valiable-inside-async-await-methods-httpclient-error-5
You are welcome to cotinue;)

My current connection class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace MicrositeEngine.Common.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class for http calls
    /// </summary>
    public class HttpClientHelper
    {
        private IDictionary<string, string> _customHeaders { get; set; }

        public HttpClientHelper() { }

        public HttpClientHelper(IDictionary<string, string> customHeader)
        {
            _customHeaders = customHeader;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Asychronously download string data from given url
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">Place for download string from</param>
        /// <returns>String data downloaded from url</returns>
        public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            using (HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(HttpRequestConsts.ContentTypeJson));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

                response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(true);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Asychronously download byte array data from given url
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">Place for download byte array from</param>
        /// <returns>Byte array data downloaded from url</returns>
        public async Task<byte[]> GetByteArrayAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            using (HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(HttpRequestConsts.ContentTypeJson));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

                response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(true);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
        }


        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
        {
            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { };
            var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

            if (_customHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in _customHeaders)
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }
            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2147483647; //max possible value

            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the message of the error?

Comment: Can you try running your app through Fiddler or Wireshark, and see if there's anything unusual about the requests the server is rejecting with 500? Or if you suspect that the HttpClient itself is generating these then this would identify that too.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddler output. It doesn't look like the .NET client is doing anything wrong then, I don't think? Is there anything in the logs on the server?

Comment: I already did this, the calls are always the same. Fiddler's request &respond added to post

Comment: Note (off topic): For performance reasons you can hold a static instance of HttpClient because initializing one for each request is cost intensive and may use too much sockets. Have a look at http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Btw, you're setting `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` to 2GB. Does your execution environment have 2GB of ram to allocate to a buffer if someone uses it to download a massive file?

Answer (score -3):

Try to use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient.

Also check with fiddler / wireshark the response of your outgoing Http-Request.

Comment: You mean [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)? [HttpWebRequest is now obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190216.aspx). Why would that solve this problem? What do you think is going wrong here?

Comment: Using HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse in most cases is more performant then using HttpClient (from System.Net import), it could be a fix for your problem. I think that the HttpClient itself generates the error, but it could also be a problem from your local machine, as a guy mentioned above, try checking with wireshark / fiddler, the responses. Also try to use HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse with a StreamReader.

Comment: I will try to use WebClient class, but I dont expect it helps.

Comment: Why you are not trying to use HttpWebRequest? I don't mean the WebClient class.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: also the link mentioned in your update3 is not working.. Can you please update the link?